# Adding an "Upload" button to an apps that can capture photo using iPhone's Camera

Tags: ios, camera, image-uploading, ipod-touch

I am a newbie of XCode and Objective-C, and I followed the example in http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPhone_Camera_Application_(Xcode_4),
and so that I have an apps that can call the camera in device (in my case, I am using iPod Touch) and capture the picture, then it can shows the picture in the image view, or select the picture in the camera roll to show in the image view. This is tested and worked perfectly in my iPod Touch.

Now, I want to add an upload button that can upload the image that captured to my server 
(e.g.: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/photo/) so that I can view the image in my computer, anyone can suggest a method to let me do so? Or if it can not be done, am I need to set-up a php based server to handle this upload problem.

Comment: If you want to just see your photo on your computer, can't you just set the image as an attachment in your in-app email ?

Comment: As I want to run the apps on iPod,  I want to upload the photo in the apps,  but not the email

Comment: @SeanCan you tell me solution for above question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanna upload an image to php server, in objective-c which you can do this :

```
//To convert your image file to raw.
NSData *imageData   = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);
NSString *urlString = @"http://sample.com/upload.php";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//Boundary and Header.
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//Your uploading file.
NSMutableData *bodyData = [NSMutableData data];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
/*
 * Declares the PHP received $_FILES variables.
 * - $_FILES['_varName']['name'] = _sample.png
 */
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"_varName\"; filename=\"_sample.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[bodyData appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[bodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
//Received response of server.
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//Dumps it.
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

May it can help you.

Comment: First of all,  thanks for the reply.  Kuo Minh Lin, you help me a big time.  But I want to ask if I need to know the name of each images,  and modify the method above each time for uploading different image?

Comment: Is there any method that can upload the image just taken by the camera?

Comment: Anything, it's happy to help you, and I wrote a sample in GitHub for you, may you can try to use it : [KRUploader](https://github.com/Kalvar/ios-KRUploader).

Comment: Thanks for helping me again. But now I setup the local server on my windows PC, and run the wamp server, and create this 

<?php

$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
   echo "YES";
} else {
  echo "NO";
}
?>

php file, and my iPod said "Undefinded index: uploaded in <b>C:\wamp\www\upload.php</b>

So, what can I do ?

Comment: May you can offer code line of php-error, or you can use a php function called var_dump() to dump the $_FILES or anything. To confirm the php is running correct. And you should be trying to echo the php error code number like this : $_FILES['uploaded']['error'].

Comment: Anything, it just a little bit. Good Luck !